# ImageField resizing on save also updating width_field and height_field

Tags: django, model, imagefield

I have a model containing `ImageField` which should be resized after uploading.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    banner = ImageField(upload_to='uploaded_images',
                        width_field='banner_width',
                        height_field='banner_height')
    banner_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('banner width'), editable=False)
    banner_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('banner height'), editable=False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    resize_image(filename=self.banner.path,
                 width=MAX_BANNER_WIDTH,
                 height=MAX_BANNER_HEIGHT)
```

`resize_image` is a custom function which does the resizing, and everything works fine, except that banner_width and banner_height are populated with dimensions of original image, before resizing.

Actual size of resized image may be smaller than MAX values given, so I have to open resized file to check it's actual dimensions after resizing. I could then manually set `banner_width` and `banner_height`, and save again, but it's not efficient way.
I could also do the resizing first, set width and height fields, and then save, but file at location `self.banner.path` doesn't exist before save is performed.

Any suggestions on how should this be done properly?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your resize_image method?  It seems like you could use some of the logic there that determines the final size of your image to set the banner_width and banner_height properties before saving, unless there is something magic going on in that method.

Comment: @CaseyKinsey  I updated this function recently to return resized image, and right now in `save` method I firstly call `super(SomeModel, self).save()` then do `resize_image()`, update `banner_width` and `banner_height`, and finally call `super(SomeModel, self).save()` again. It works, although I'd like to avoid saving model instance twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of trying to do this efficiently, I've changed my approach to this problem and defined `CustomImageField` like this:

```
class CustomImageField(ImageField):
    attr_class = CustomImageFieldFile

    def __init__(self, resize=False, to_width=None, to_height=None, force=True, *args, **kwargs):
        self.resize = resize
        if resize:
            self.to_width = to_width
            self.to_height = to_height
            self.force = force
        super(CustomImageField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class CustomImageFieldFile(ImageFieldFile): 

    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        super(CustomImageFieldFile, self).save(name, content, save=save)
        if self.field.resize:
            resized_img = resize_image(filename=self.path,
                                       width=self.field.to_width,
                                       height=self.field.to_height,
                                       force=self.field.force)
            if resized_img:
                setattr(self.instance, self.field.width_field, resized_img.size[0])
                setattr(self.instance, self.field.height_field, resized_img.size[1])
```

Now I can just define:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    my_image = CustomImageField(resize=True, to_width=SOME_WIDTH, to_height=SOME_HEIGHT, force=False,
                                width_field='image_width', height_field='image_height')
    image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)
    image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)
```

And depending on `resize` argument, image can be automatically resized after uploading, and width/height fields are correctly updated, without saving object twice. After quick tests it seems to be working fine.